# Where is the result of the query is stored?

Tags: 7, views

I have created a view page and a block. I need to get the query from the view block. The query preview can be seen.

The following code was found to fetch the query from view

```
function status_update_views_pre_execute(&$view) {
 if ($view->name == 'project_initiative') {
   $query = (string)$view->build_info['query'];
   echo $query;
 }
}
```

Where is the result of the query stored? How can I fetch it?

OR

the query is as follows

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.created AS node_created, 'node' AS field_data_body_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_project_name_node_entity_type FROM  {node} node LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_project_name} field_data_field_project_name ON node.nid = field_data_field_project_name.entity_id AND (field_data_field_project_name.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_project_name.deleted = '0') WHERE (( (field_data_field_project_name.field_project_name_target_id = '55' ) )AND(( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('status_update')) ))) ORDER BY node_created DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

How can I execute it to get the result in drupal custom module?

Comment: what exactly do you plan on doing with it?

Comment: @NoSssweat The query will return a set of nodes from which I want to create a timeline with its date fields.

Comment: have you tried $query->execute(); ? 
It will turn in an endless loop if you execute it in this hook, though.
To get the results of the views query you should use views_pre_render hook there it will be executed.

Comment: @Insasse I have changed the question. please check. The query should have a result. the result is a set of nodes and where or how can I achieve it?

Comment: You can execute this query whereever you want, but maybe you want to check this-> https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/group/database/7.x first.

Depends on the context you need to execute the query.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the nids like this:

```
// load and display view
$view = views_get_view('view_name');
$view->set_display('block_1');
$view->execute();
$nids = [];
// get all nids from the result 
foreach ($view->result as $result) {
   $nids[] = $result->nid;
}
// render view
print $view->render();
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. Thank you for your response though!

Comment: I am trying to explicitly ran the query and fetch the results(node id
)

Comment: @RonySamuel should've worked. Did the view print? if not, then you did not enter the correct value in line 1 or line 2. For line 2 you need to set the correct [machine name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDJ1q.jpg) OR unless.. is your view using contextual filter? I did not set that here.